# Can't install indy-sdk in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: hyperledger, ubuntu-20.04, hyperledger-indy

I want to install indy-sdk in ubuntu 20.04, but I can't find any  documentation about it.
How can I install it?

Comment: please provide more info about the error

Answer (score 1):

Check if stable nodejs is installed. Try with node version greater then 10.

Follow below commands to install indy-sdk on ubuntu 20.04

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
gnupg \ 
ca-certificates

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys CE7709D068DB5E88

echo "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/sdk/deb bionic stable" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
libindy
```

Then you can install via npm:

```
npm install --save indy-sdk
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/indy-sdk

Comment: Be more specific, like why it works only with node version 10.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the installation process here : https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk#ubuntu-based-distributions-ubuntu-1604-and-1804

Comment: I tried this but still not working. It is saying file not found.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This, I have used the bionic version on ubuntu 20.04 and its worked.**

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 68DB5E88
>
> sudo add-apt-repository “deb https://repo.sovrin.org/sdk/deb bionic
> master”
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y libindy

There will be a file not found error if we write the repository incorrectly in apt-get. You can get the command on https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk#ubuntu-based-distributions-ubuntu-1604-and-1804.

if you write wrong in this section, the file not found error will appear

> sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/sdk/deb
> (xenial|bionic) {release channel}"

So, dont use the () and {}, as follows :

> sudo add-apt-repository “deb https://repo.sovrin.org/sdk/deb bionic
> master”